# CGContextFillRect not drawing a rectangle?

Tags: iphone, core-graphics

I have this code:

```
CGColorRef darkColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:21.0/255.0 green:92.0/255.0 blue:136.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor];
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, darkColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(18, 62, 66, 66));
```

And I just put it in the viewdidload method of my view, but my view doesn't look any different than before. I've tried making it really big and bright red, but it's just not drawing. Is there some other initialization code that I need?

EDIT: After working with the answers given to me, I have this now in my veiwdidload:

```
[self.view addSubview:[[[imageBackground alloc] init] autorelease]];
```

and in imageBackground.m:

```
@implementation imageBackground

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.opaque = YES;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    return self;
}


// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGColorRef darkColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:21.0/255.0 green:92.0/255.0 blue:136.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor];
    darkColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, darkColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(18, 62, 66, 66));
}
@end
```

Imagebackground.h subclasses UIView:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface imageBackground : UIView
@end
```

I still get no results out of it though.

EDIT2: Well, I solved it myself, but then realized progrmr had already told me how to solve it. I had to use `[self.view addSubview:[[[imageBackground alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)] autorelease]];` instead of just plain alloc init.

Thanks glorifiedhacker for lots of help as well!

Comment: Does your drawRect method hit?

Comment: You didn't invoke initWithFrame, so there is no frame set.

Comment: progrmr is right - the imageBackground you create in viewDidLoad has a frame with origin {0,0} and a size {0,0}. You need to set the frame of the view before it will be drawn.

Comment: I thought you were drawing this among other things in the view. It seems not like so why don't do `UIView *square = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(18,62,66,66)];` `square setColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:21.0/255.0 green:92.0/255.0 blue:136.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];` `[self.view addSubview:square];`  `[square release]`; in your viewDidLoad method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to subclass UIView (or one of its subclasses) and override the drawRect method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGColorRef darkColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:21.0/255.0 green:92.0/255.0 blue:136.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, darkColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(18, 62, 66, 66));
}
```

in order to get a valid graphics context into which you can draw. From Apple's [documentation on UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html):

> View drawing occurs on an as-needed basis. When a view is first shown,
>   or when all or part of it becomes visible due to layout changes, the
>   system asks the view to draw its contents. For views that contain
>   custom content using UIKit or Core Graphics, the system calls the
>   view’s drawRect: method. Your implementation of this method is
>   responsible for drawing the view’s content into the current graphics
>   context, which is set up by the system automatically prior to calling
>   this method. This creates a static visual representation of your
>   view’s content that can then be displayed on the screen.

Comment: Well, I added the drawRect method to my view, which is a subclass of UIViewController, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Is there something I have to do first? I'll check the documentation you linked to.

Comment: A view is NOT a subclass of UIViewController. In order to do custom drawing in a view, you need to subclass UIView (not UIViewController) and override the drawRect: method of UIView.

Comment: Ok, so I make a new class that's a subclass of UIView. But how do I tell it that I want its drawRect to be called when the view is loaded?

Comment: Reading the documentation that I linked to will help you immensely. For example, it will explain that a UIView's drawRect: method is called automatically when it is asked to draw itself on the screen. You will never need to invoke drawRect: directly.

Comment: I did read that, but it never knows to call this file because I never initialized it anywhere. I tried [self.view addSubview:[[[imageBackground alloc] init] autorelease]]; but that didn't work.

Comment: 1. subclass UIView and override -drawRect: as glorifiedHacker said.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the code for your ViewController and the code for your UIView subclass.

Comment: if using IB: 2. select the view of the view controller and set its class to be the same class as the one you just created. If you are not using IB: 2. in the loadView you should be creating the view, set it `self.view = [[[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];`

Comment: I posted the code using the new subclass of UIView. And @nacho4d, I don't want to make the entire view this new one.

Answer (score 1):

The most simply way, without subclassing, is a procedure for whole code.

```
void DrawRectFrame(CGContext c, CGRect rc)
{
    CGContextMoveToPoint(c,     rc.origin.x,                  rc.origin.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c,  rc.origin.x+rc.size.width,    rc.origin.y);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(c,     rc.origin.x+rc.size.width,    rc.origin.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c,  rc.origin.x+rc.size.width,    rc.origin.y+rc.size.height);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(c,     rc.origin.x+rc.size.width,    rc.origin.y+rc.size.height);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c,  rc.origin.x,                   rc.origin.y+rc.size.height);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(c,     rc.origin.x,                   rc.origin.y+rc.size.height);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c,  rc.origin.x,                   rc.origin.y);
}
```